# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence - after making TF_IDF vectorization

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I'm new to data science and NLP. I want to perform TF_IDF vectorization on some text documents and after use the results to train different machine learning models. But when I try to train SVC model I obtain the ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Here is my code.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')
df['vect_message'] = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['message_encoding'])
X = df['vect_message']
y = df['severity']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

from sklearn import svm
model = svm.SVC() 
model.fit(X_train, y_train) 
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

And I got an error on the line `model.fit(X_train, y_train)`

I have already searched other similar questions and I found one where they advise using `.toarray()` method to transform sparse matrix into np.array. But this didn't help me.

Comment: what was the error you received?

Comment: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the following line:

```
df['vect_message'] = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['message_encoding'])
```

Pandas treats the result of `vectorizer.fit_transform()` as a **scalar** object.
As a result you will have the same sparse matrix in every row in the `vect_message` column:

```
In [74]: df.loc[0, 'vect_message']
Out[74]:
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [75]: df.loc[0, 'vect_message'].A
Out[75]:
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.70710678],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])

In [76]: df.loc[1, 'vect_message'].A
Out[76]:
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.70710678],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])

In [77]: df.loc[2, 'vect_message'].A
Out[77]:
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.70710678],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Basically the same is happening when we do `df['new_col'] = 0` - we will have a column of `zeros`

**Workaround:**

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['message_encoding'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

PS IMO it doesn't make much sense to save (well to try to save) 2D sparse matrix (result of `vectorizer.fit_transform()` call in Pandas column (Series) - 1D structure)

Comment: And if I change my code as you show, then will I get the feature for EVERY training example?

Comment: @DmitrijBurlaj, give it a try! ;)

Comment: Actually, I have tried already and there is no longer an error, but an accuracy is not very high, so I want to just make sure if this is a correct way to do machine learning :)

Comment: So thank you a lot, it seems that you answer helped me to deal with my problem!

Comment: @DmitrijBurlaj, glad i could help :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe you can help me with one more thing?) I need to add some more features to this matrix which I got from TfidfVectorizer. How can I do this? When I try to call ```pd.DataFrame(X.toarray())``` then I receive the error message: ```ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.```

Comment: @DmitrijBurlaj, you can try to create a Sparse DataFrame: `pd.SparseDataFrame(X)` ...